# Importing a Postgresql datadump into AWS RDS PostgreSQL database

Tags: bash, postgresql, amazon-ec2, plpgsql, amazon-rds

```
#!/bin/bash

psql -d awsdbname -U username --host=sometinhing.1.rds.amazonaws.com  --
port=5432 **somename** < datadump.pgsql
```

I am trying to run the above bash script to get the data dump on my local to a Postgresql database on AWS. Following is the error I am getting -->

```
psql: warning: extra command-line argument **"somename"** ignored
```

Is something wrong with the syntax? please help.

Comment: You don't need the -d and the last parameter - they both specify the database name.

Comment: I would suggest that "**somename**" would need a flag associated with it.

Comment: The last parameter "datadump.pgsql" is the dump stored on my local that I want to insert into the aws database "awsdbname"

Comment: No, the last parameter before the redirect (<) is the database name again.

Comment: @stdunbar thanks man! that worked!